# How to get contents of a node and preserve inner tags

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT, given something like this:

```
<summary>
    Blah, blah, blah <code>foo</code> blah <code>bar</code> blah.
</summary>
```

How would you transform it into something like:

```
<div>
    Blah, blah, blah <code>foo</code> blah <code>bar</code> blah.
<div>
```

I started out, in my XSLT, with something like:

```
<div>
    <xsl:value-of select="summary"/>
</div>
```

But this will transform into:

```
<div>
    Blah, blah, blah foo blah bar blah.
<div>
```

In other words, I lost the inner `<code>`. I then tried

```
<div>
    <xsl:copy-of select="summary"/>
</div>
```

But that'll give me:

```
<div>
    <summary>
        Blah, blah, blah <code>foo</code> blah <code>bar</code> blah.
    </summary>
</div>
```

In other words, the `<summary>` tag that I aimed to replace is included.

Then I started getting creative:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="summary/*"/>
```

Only outputs the contents of the `<code>` tags

```
<xsl:copy-of select="summary/text()"/>
```

Removes the `<code>` tags and their contents entirely.

So is there a way to make this work? Select the contents of the `summary` tag (without the `summary` tag itself) and preserve any inner tags?

Comment: As well as the solutions given by others using `xsl:apply-templates`, you could do `<xsl:copy-of select="summary/node()"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an identity template and a replace template with `xsl:apply-templates` inside like this:

```
<!-- identity template - copies all nodes -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- replace template - more specific element template -->
<xsl:template match="summary">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

**Result:**

```
<div>
    Blah, blah, blah <code>foo</code> blah <code>bar</code> blah.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to transform the `summary` element into a `div` then write a template doing that

```
  <xsl:template match="summary">
      <div>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then you only need to make sure the rest is copied unchanged which you can do in XSLT 3 (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDba) with

```
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

or in earlier versions by spelling out the identity transformation as a template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```